# Meaning and synonyms of 'toll' in 'death toll'

Tags: meaning, synonyms

As a foreign locutor..., the word *toll* seems weird in the following sentence in The New York Times:

> Death **Toll** Rises From Wind and Flooding

Automatic translations do not help very much : without, costs, number, call, toll ?

Could you give me other examples of sentences with the word *toll*, or provide synonyms for it?

Comment: It's a dead metaphor. It's a nice short way of saying 'how many people died'.

Comment: @Mitch:  In the expression "funeral toll" cited by mhoran_psprep, is it a tax/charge or something else ?

Comment: @Trimok Read through the [dictionary definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/toll), [thesaurus entry](http://thesaurus.com/browse/death+toll?s=t), and a nice run down on the [etymology](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dea6.htm) of _death toll_.

Comment: @coleopterist: Thanks, the [etymology](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dea6.htm) reference was very interesting.

Comment: 'Never send to know for whom the bell tolls; it tolls for thee' (John Donne).

Comment: I've never heard the phrase 'funeral toll' but is makes sense when 'toll' is for 'the sounding of a bell', not for a fee.

Comment: @Mitch: (and Barrie England) OK, I understand this is a sound: there is an equivalent french expression "Pour qui sonne le glas ?"

Comment: No man is an island, entire of itself; every man is a piece of the continent, a part of the main. If a clod be washed away by the sea, Europe is the less, as well as if a promontory were, as well as if a manor of thy friend's or of thine own were: any man's death diminishes me, because I am involved in mankind, and therefore never send to know for whom the bells tolls; it tolls for thee. (John Donne)

Comment: Ah, Ok, there is also the Hemingway book  "For whom the bells tolls"

Comment: @Trimok Did you say one translation could be “without”? I can't think of any context where “toll” can mean “without”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Toll* in this case means cost or count. It is the count of the number that died from the storm.

You will also see it referring to money; many times it is a synonym for tariff or tax:

- Toll road (you pay a fee per mile)
- Toll bridge (you pay to cross the bridge)
- Toll booth (The place where you pay to cross the bridge or use the road)
- Toll call (A telephone call that you pay per minute or per call)

*Toll* can also refer to bells: a funeral *toll*.